# Encoding and efficient IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell, encoding, bytestring

Hello i am a bit confused about all the Haskell modules needed for encoding data from `String` to `ByteString` for efficient writing.

I do not understand how you convert a `Data.ByteString.Lazy` to a `Data.ByteString.Char8` and vice versa.

What do i need to know ? Because i can't get all these possible combinations of usages ....
`Data.ByteString`,`Data.ByteString.Lazy`,`Data.ByteString.Char8` , then there's `Data.Text`.....what do i need in order to write strings to files easily and efficiently and vice -versa? (with proper encoding)

**P.S** Currently reading Real World Haskell and i got pretty confused on all these modules.

Comment: You don't normally need `Data.ByteString.Char8` at all. You want `Data.Text` when dealing with text and `Data.ByteString` when dealing with binary data of some sort or another. Also, converting `String` to `ByteString` "for efficient writing" doesn't really make a whole lot of sense; Just keep your data in a `ByteString` in the first place if that's a reasonable representation.

Comment: There are two `ByteString` types, lazy and strict. They store raw bytes, not characters. The `Char8` variants are not separate types; they're just modules that expose a slightly different interface (effectively treating `ByteString` as Latin-1 text). `String` and `Text` store Unicode characters (i.e. text).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a shot at a roadmap.

### Strings and Text

As you are probably aware, the Haskell `String` type is just a type synonym for `[Char]`, where `Char` is a data type that can represent a single Unicode code point.  This makes `String` the perfect data type to represent textual data, except for the minor issue that -- as a linked list of boxed `Char` values -- it has the potential to be extremely inefficient.

The `Text` data type from the `text` package addresses this issue.  `Text` is also, like `String`, a representation of a list of `Char` values, but instead of using an actual Haskell list, it uses a time and space-efficient representation.  It should be your go-to replacement for `String` whenever you need to work efficiently with textual (Unicode) data.

Like many other data types in the standard Haskell libraries, it comes in lazy and strict variants.  Both variants have the same name `Text`, but they are contained in separate modules, so you might do:

```
import qualified Data.Text as TS
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as TL
```

if you needed to use both `TS.Text` and `TL.Text` variants in the same program.

The exact difference between variants is described in the [documentation for Data.Text](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text.html).  In a nutshell, you should default to using the strict version.  You only use the lazy version in two cases.  First, if you're planning to work on a large `Text` value a little bit at a time, treating it more like a text "stream" than a "string", then the lazy version is a good choice.  (For example, a program to read a huge CSV file of numbers might read the file as a long lazy `Text` stream and store the results in an efficient numeric type like a `Vector` of unboxed `Double` values to avoid keeping the whole input text in memory.)  Second, if you're building a large `Text` string up from lots of little pieces, then you don't want to use the strict versions, because their immutability means they need to be copied whenever you add something.  Instead, you'd want to use the lazy variant with functions from `Data.Text.Lazy.Builder`.

### ByteStrings

The `ByteString` data type from the `bytestring` package, on the other hand, is an efficient representation of a list of bytes.  Just like `Text` is an efficient version of `[Char]`, you should think of `ByteString` as an efficient version of `[Word8]`, where `Word8` is the Haskell type representing a single unsigned byte of data with value 0-255.  Equivalently, you can think of a `ByteString` as representing a chunk of memory or a chunk of data to be read from or written to a file, precisely as-is byte for byte.  It also comes in lazy and strict flavors:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
```

and the considerations for using the variants are similar to those for `Text`.

### Reading and Writing to Files

In a Haskell program, it's usual to represent Unicode strings internally as either `String` or `Text` values.  However, to read them in from or write them out to files, they need to be encoded into and decoded from sequences of bytes.

The simplest way of dealing with this is to use Haskell functions that handle the encoding and decoding automatically.  As you are probably aware, there are already two functions in the `Prelude` that read and write strings directly:

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String
writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
```

In addition, there are `readFile` and `writeFile` functions in `text` that do this.  You can find versions in both `Data.Text.IO` and `Data.Text.Lazy.IO`.  They appear to have the same signatures, but one is operating on the strict `Text` type and the other is operating on the lazy `Text` type:

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO Text
writeFile :: FilePath -> Text -> IO ()
```

You can tell these functions are doing the encoding and decoding automatically because they return and accept `Text` values, not `ByteString` values.  The default encoding used will depend on the operating system and its configuration.  On a typical modern Linux distribution, it'll be UTF-8.

Alternatively, you can read or write the raw bytes from the file using functions from the `bytestring` package (again, either lazy or strict versions, depending on the module):

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO ByteString
writeFile :: FilePath -> ByteString -> IO ()
```

These have the same names as the `text` versions, but you can see they are dealing with raw bytes because they return and accept `ByteString` arguments.  In this case, if you want to use these `ByteString`s as text data, you'll need to decode or encode them yourself.  If the `ByteString` represents a UTF-8 encoded version of the text for example, then these functions from `Data.Text.Encoding` (for strict versions) or `Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding` (for lazy versions) are what you're looking for:

```
decodeUtf8 :: ByteString -> Text
encodeUtf8 :: Text -> ByteString
```

### The Char8 Modules

Now, the modules in `Data.ByteString.Char8` and `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` are a special case.  When plain ASCII text has been encoded using one of several "ASCII-preserving" encoding schemes (including ASCII itself, Latin-1 and other Latin-x encodings, and UTF-8), it turns out that the encoded `ByteString` is just a simple one-byte-per-character encoding of Unicode code points 0 to 127.  Slightly more generally, when text has been encoded in Latin-1, then the encoded `ByteString` is just a simple one-byte-per-character encoding of Unicode code points 0 to 255.  In these cases, and in these cases only, the functions in these modules can be safely used to bypass the explicit encoding and decoding steps and just treat the byte string as ASCII and/or Latin-1 text directly by automaticaly converting single bytes to unicode `Char` values and back.

Because these functions only work in that special case, you should generally avoid using them except in specialized applications.

Also, as was mentioned in a comment, the `ByteString` variants in these `Char8` modules are not any different than the plain strict and lazy `ByteString` variants; the are just treated as if they are strings of `Char` values instead of `Word8` values by the *functions* in those modules -- the data types are the same, just the function interface is different.

### General Strategy

So, if you're working with plain text and your operating system's default coding, just use the strict `Text` data type from `Data.Text` and the (highly efficient) IO functions from `Data.Text.IO`.  You can use the lazy variants for stream processing or building big strings from tiny pieces, and you can use `Data.Text.Read` for some simple parsing.

You should be able to avoid using `String` at all in most situations, but if you find you need to convert back and forth, then these conversion functions in `Data.Text` (or `Data.Text.Lazy`) will be useful:

```
pack :: String -> Text
unpack :: Text -> String
```

If you need more control over the encoding, you *still* want to use `Text` throughout your program, except at the "edges" where you're reading or writing files.  At those edges, use the I/O functions from `Data.ByteString` (or `Data.ByteString.Lazy`), and the encoding/decoding functions from `Data.Text.Encoding` or `Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding`.

If you find you need to mix strict and lazy variants, note that `Data.Text.Lazy` contains:

```
toStrict :: TL.Text -> TS.Text     -- convert lazy to strict
fromStrict :: TS.Text -> TL.Text   -- vice versa
```

and `Data.ByteString.Lazy` contains the corresponding functions for `ByteString` values:

```
toStrict :: BL.ByteString -> BS.ByteString
fromStrict :: BS.ByteString -> BL.ByteString
```

Comment: But how do you convert from`ByteString` to `Text` and vice versa ?

Comment: I've updated the end of the `Reading and Writing Files` section to make it clearer.  The answer is that the conversion functions used depend on the encoding, but *IF* the `ByteString` is a UTF-8 encoded version of the text, then `encodeUtf8` and `decodeUtf8` from `Data.Text.Encoding` are the conversion functions you want.

Comment: _"the (highly efficient) IO functions from `Data.Text.IO`"_ -- these functions are not efficient, see e.g. ["Beware of `readFile`](https://www.snoyman.com/blog/2016/12/beware-of-readfile/): _"The I/O functions from the `text` package are significantly slower than using bytestring-based I/O and then decoding [...] it is inherent in Handle-based character I/O, which involves copying all data through a buffer of `Word32` values" . Further, `Data.Text.IO` functions lead to surprising encoding errors. See https://github.com/haskell/text/issues/446#issuecomment-1619375187 for examples and solution.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the kind of data you're dealing with and how you plan to hand that data.

If you're dealing with Unicode strings, use `Text` from Text package.

If you don't need to read all data into memory at once, use the `Lazy` version of that module. Otherwise, the entire data will be loaded in a single data structure.

When to use `Data.ByteString` or `Data.ByteString.Char8` depends on what you want that bytestring to represent: a sequence of bytes or sequence of 8-bit characters. A `ByteString` is a data structure you can use to store either a sequence of bytes, each of type: `Word8` or a sequence of 8-bit characters, each of type: `Char`. There is only one `ByteString` type.

Because often we may deal with binary data mixed with character-based data, it would be convenient if we keep operations for bytes and characters separately in different modules; that way when we need to handle character based data, just use operations from the Char8 modules.